# Counting Distinct and Unique user logins per day in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to count how many distinct and unique user_IDs have logged in for the first time to the website. Below is the SQL query that counts distinct user_IDs based on the condition that its their first_hit at the website. But I am not sure whether if the same user is logging in different days. One user login should be counted only once(unique).

The first query that I wrote:

```
select
    --'Jan 2017' as month,
    to_char(first_hit_at::date,'dd-mm-yyyy') as date,
    count( distinct a.user_id ) as unique_user_logins_in_month
from
      stg_marketing.ga_sessions a
where
    a.first_hit_at >('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    and a.first_hit_at <('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000')
    and user_login_state = 'true' 
    group by 1
    order by 1
```

Second improved query:

```
select
    --'Jan 2017' as month,
    to_char(first_hit_at::date,'dd-mm-yyyy') as date,
    count( distinct a.user_id ) as unique_user_logins_in_month
from
    stg_marketing.ga_sessions a
where
    a.first_hit_at >('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    and a.first_hit_at <('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000')
    and user_login_state = 'true' 
    and last_hit_at::date > first_hit_at::date 
    group by 1
    order by 1
```

Result of query one:

```
date         unique_user_logins_in_month
01-01-2017   7008
02-01-2017   11023
03-01-2017   10318
04-01-2017   10091
05-01-2017   8726
```

Result of query two:

```
  date        unique_user_logins_in_month
  01-01-2017  97
  02-01-2017  96
  03-01-2017  62
  04-01-2017  61
  05-01-2017  69
```

I am not sure if both are queries are correct or second one is more correct. Thanks

Comment: i don't understand  "But I am not sure whether if the same user is logging in different days", why do you care if the user logged in the day after or not ? `first_hit_at` is the the first time you see the user right ?  . can you post the table structure ?

Comment: @AkliREGUIG I have added two queries and the output result of both. could you please have a look now? Thanks

Comment: I can't help without the table structure and constraints. what tool/ETL you used for pushing GA data into postgres ?

Answer (score 0):

> how many distinct and unique user_IDs have logged in for the first
>   time to the website.

The user is logging in for the first time if she has never logged in in the past.
You can find log entries for such users using NOT EXISTS operator (this is so called ANTI JOIN):

```
select *
from
      stg_marketing.ga_sessions a
where
    a.first_hit_at >('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    and a.first_hit_at <('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000')
    and user_login_state = 'true' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        select * from stg_marketing.ga_sessions b
        where a.user_id = b.user_id
          and b.first_hit_at < a.first_hit_at
    )
```

Now just do an aggregation on a result of the above query

```
select 
     to_char(first_hit_at::date,'dd-mm-yyyy') as date,
     count( distinct a.user_id ) as unique_user_logins_in_month
from
      stg_marketing.ga_sessions a
where
    a.first_hit_at >('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    and a.first_hit_at <('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000')
    and user_login_state = 'true' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        select * from stg_marketing.ga_sessions b
        where a.user_id = b.user_id
          and b.first_hit_at < a.first_hit_at
    )
group by to_char(first_hit_at::date,'dd-mm-yyyy')
```